# How to concatenate an array of number into one total number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, push

I'm trying to take an array of any length of ints, and concatenate it into a single number that is the total added up. For instance, if I have an array that goes as follows: [2, 2] I want it to  becomes [4].

I'm currently using a for loop to generate the array using .push() on checkboxes and require the total to add it to another equation.

I'm trying to do this for the price array:

```
for(var i=0; i < toppings.length; i++){ // CREATES LOOP FOR EXTRA DATA
           if(toppings[i].checked) { //IF CHECKED
              storeExtNames += products[productsList.selectedIndex].extra[i].name + " ";
              storeExtPrice.push(products[productsList.selectedIndex].extra[i].price);
           }//END IF
        }//END LOOP
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Sum_all_the_values_of_an_array

Comment: `push` does not add. I believe you are looking for `+`.

Comment: "Concatenate" means to put two strings together, one after the other. So '1' + '2' + '14' is '1214' in languages that allow you to use the + operator on strings to concatenate, but what you describe is just addition, not concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the array like this:

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
while (arr.length > 1) {
    arr[0] += arr.pop();
}
```